# A problem in calculating integral

Tags: integration

I have a problem in calculating the integral:
$I=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{xe^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
dx$.

My teacher said that $\dfrac{xe^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is an odd function, thus $I=0$.

This is my solution, but I wonder if it's right.
$I=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{xe^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
dx=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}d(\dfrac{x^2}{2})=0$

Is the statement $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{xe^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
dx=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}d(\dfrac{x^2}{2})$ right?

My teacher said that $f(x)=\dfrac{xe^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ needs to be injective so that we can write as above, but I can't find any theorem confirm that. Anyone help me please?

Comment: Your lower limit after change of variable is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for caring about my problems, But can you tell me how to correct it?

Comment: I still don't understand why my lower limit is wrong. I mean that x goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: I added an answer, does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I'm stil reading it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the substitution $u=z(x)$
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_{z(a)}^{z(b)} f(z^{-1}(u))\frac{dz^{-1}(u)}{du}\,du
$$

which tells us if our substitution is valid,  $z$ has to be invertible or equivalently $z$ is an injective function over the required domain. Now in your post $$u=\frac{x^2}{2}\implies z(x)=\frac{x^2}{2},\quad x\in(-\infty,+\infty)$$
But this $z$ is indeed not injective over $\mathbb R$ as
$$z(x)=z(-x)$$
The way you have used substitution the lower limit should be $z(-\infty)=+\infty\,$.
[Wikipedia page on u-substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definition) has the theorem you're looking for (most likely).

Comment: Thank you. But in the theorem you mentioned, it didn't include the condition of injective. By the way, I wrote $d(x^2/2)$ means that the limits is for x not for $x^2/2$. Isn't it right?

Comment: @liverpool29 I'm not aware of any such convention (however it might be correct). Note that in the Wikipedia theorem the limits in LHS are $\phi(a),\phi(b)$. Suppose we had $\phi(a')=\phi(a)$ with $a'\neq a$, we'd be in trouble figuring out the correct limit for RHS wouldn't we?

Comment: I have edited my question more clearly.

Comment: @liverpool29 [A little scrolling on the same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) leads you to a theorem that requires $\varphi$ to be injective.

Answer (score 1):

Break the integral into two parts, integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ in one part and from $-\infty$ to $0$ in the other. The substitution $x^2/2=y$ is injective over each part.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need injective condition to $\varphi(x) = x^2$ on the intergration domain, say $[-\infty , \infty]$. However, on this domian, $\varphi$ is not injective. Why don't you split the integral into 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \int_{-\infty}^{0} + \int_{0}^{\infty} 
$$
so that $\varphi$ can be an injective function on those sub-domains, thus you can follow the way as in your post, which results $I=0$ as well.

For further reference, one can read at [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), herein we can see that the injective condition is to guaranteed that the integration domain can not be overlapped via the transformation $\varphi$, e.g. in your problem $\varphi([0,\infty)) = [0 , \infty) = \varphi((-\infty,0]) \overset{overlapped \, right \, here}{=} \varphi((-\infty,\infty)) $.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is in my third sentence(in the first post), the second "=' is it right?

Comment: The second "=" is right, however, the third "=" is not certain and you need to prove it. An easy way to show it is to split the integration domain into sub-domains.

Comment: Oh thanks, this is the answer I waiting for, the third '=' I wrote in the short way. My teacher said that the second '=' is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, substitute $\text{u}=-\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $\text{d}\text{u}=-x\space\text{d}x$:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int x\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\space\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\exp\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=\text{C}-\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Now:

1. $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left\{-\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right\}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=0$$
2. $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left\{-\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right\}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=0$$